# Sequencing logic per entity while threading in Biztalk

Tags: multithreading, biztalk

I have messages that have to be published to a JMS Queue. The messages are identified by an item id and the messages having the same item id should be published in a certain sequence.

I'm considering to use threads and worried that multiple threads would not care about the sequencing logic. Is it possible to run threads so that only one thread takes care of messages with the same item id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need to enable the **[Ordered delivery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559637.aspx)** on the send port to the JMS Queue and ensure that the messages for that port are published to the message box in the order you want them put onto the queue.

By enabling Ordered delivery you are basically making it into a single thread and that does have some performance implications, although they have improved on that in the latest versions of BizTalk.